# What is the complexity of subscribing (+=) and unsubscribing (-=) a delegate in c#?

Tags: c#

What is the complexity of subscribing (+=) and unsubscribing (-=)  a delegate in c#?

```
namespace MulticastDelegateDemo
{
    public delegate void MathDelegate(int No1, int No2);

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Add(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("THE SUM IS : " + (x + y));
        }
        public static void Sub(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("THE SUB IS : " + (x - y));
        }
        public void Mul(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("THE MUL IS : " + (x * y));
        }
        public void Div(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("THE DIV IS : " + (x / y));
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            MathDelegate del1 = new MathDelegate(Add);
            MathDelegate del2 = new MathDelegate(Program.Sub);
            MathDelegate del3 = p.Mul;
            MathDelegate del4 = new MathDelegate(p.Div); ;

            //In this example del5 is a multicast delegate. We can use +(plus) 
            // operator to chain delegates together and -(minus) operator to remove.
            MathDelegate del5 = del1 + del2 + del3 + del4;
            del5.Invoke(20, 5);
            Console.WriteLine();
            del5 -= del2;
            del5(22, 7);
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean like BigO? There isn't one. BigO complexity applies to algorithms, subscribing a delegate is a simple action

Comment: whenever we subscribe to any action , how it is stored in the memory? like an array or like a list? if it is an array kind of structure which is store in the stack the whenever we add any new action to it , It will create a new memory same like an array with old array length +1  and deallocate the old memory and the complexity with be O(n)
but if it stores like a list (single link-list) then the complexity  of adding O(1) and removing is O(n)

Comment: How here I want to know how it is working internally in c# , which can be expressed in terms of  complexity

Comment: Delegates are immutable, so it is always O(n) to take care of the copying.  You just never notice, n is always very small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribing (`+=`) and unsubscribing  (`-=`) are actually shorthands for  [`System.Delegate.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.combine?view=netcore-3.1) and [`System.Delegate.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.remove?view=netcore-3.1) static methods invocations. They internally call correspondingly `CombineImpl` and `RemoveImpl` for passed delegates pairs (with some exclusions for cases with null parameters passed).

You can check the actual implementation yourself on [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/). There you can see that for [`MulticastDelegate.CombineImpl`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/MulticastDelegate.cs,fcbf8bdc05d28aeb) complexity is `O(m)` where `m` is number of items in the right operand invocation list:

```
Action act = null; int count = 25000; var sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Action a = () => Console.WriteLine(); 
    act = (a += act);
}
Console.WriteLine($"Subscribe - {count}: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); // prints "Subscribe - 25000: 1662" on my machine

sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     act += () => Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine($"Subscribe - {count}: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}"); // prints "Subscribe - 25000: 2" on my machine
```

As for [`MulticastDelegate.RemoveImpl`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/MulticastDelegate.cs,89414467eca8bd75) it get's harder to quickly estimate the complexity, but it seems to be `O(n)` (where `n` is number of items in the right operand invocation list) for cases where `n` > `m`.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation will be compiler dependent; however based on the interface, restrictions and use cases it would be easiest and most likely most efficient to implement the backend using linked lists.  The main impact would be on unsubscribe lookups.

You can subscribe the same delegate multiple times in Visual Studio 19 (huge performance hit if you leak that dozens of times) so the implementation is obviously just appending what you give it.

Doing a simple loop test subscribe is significantly faster and unsubscribe is kicking the fan in on my laptop

This is using the StopWatch class and ElapsedMilliseconds - The classes are empty outside of the standard event declaration and methods.

```
Looping 50000 times
Subscribe: 15
Unsubscribe: 9202
```

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EventSubscirber ms = new EventSubscirber();
            MyEventClass myEventClass = new MyEventClass();

            int loops = 50000;

            Stopwatch swsubscribe = new Stopwatch();
            Stopwatch swunsubscribe = new Stopwatch();

            swsubscribe.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
            {
                myEventClass.SampleEvent += ms.SampleEventReceiver;
            }
            swsubscribe.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Looping {loops} times");
            Console.WriteLine($"Subscribe: {swsubscribe.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

            swunsubscribe.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
            {
                myEventClass.SampleEvent -= ms.SampleEventReceiver;
            }

            swunsubscribe.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Unsubscribe: {swunsubscribe.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        }
```

Just guessing, but based on timing, its iterating the full list each time and unsubscribing the last one that matches.

Comment: Yes look at the code feels like internal it is implemented like a list where subscribing to any new action is very efficient (as if O(1))  but unsubscribing is costly (O(n)). I was checking the Microsoft documentation, no-where they have mentioned the complexity of subscribing and unsubscribing

Comment: Still, it is unclear about the internal implementation of delegates. So anyway I was planning to implement the observer and listener design pattern for which I was thinking of using events and delegates as a mode of communication but I was not sure to use this (as complexity is never mentioned anywhere in official documentation ) or create my own system with a double link list as the complexity of adding and removing is O(1) because in my case there is a lot of adding/subscribing and removing/unsubscribing operations are happing very frequently

Comment: It will really help if someone can add a link for documentation of event and delegate (C#) where the complexity of subscribing and unsubscribing is mentioned

Comment: This wouldn't be in the documentation because it would be implementation specific.  The implementation can change but the behavior to the user cannot.